# Having a hard time understanding how cascade delete works and how to configure relationships

Tags: c#, database, ef-core-2.2

So, I have the dependent entity `ArtItem`, with parent class `Location`, which is a dependent entity of `Company`, which is a dependent entity of `Country`. `ArtItem` is also dependent on `Artist` and `Artist` is dependent on `Country`.

```
public class Country
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

public class Company
    {
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

public class Location
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        //public List<ArtItem> ArtItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArtItem
    {
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Artist
    {
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

My issue is that whenever I try to do update-database in powershell, I get the error `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ArtItems_Locations_LocationId' on table 'ArtItems' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.`.

I tried configuring the relationship in my `DbContext` class,
[image: DbContext]
.

but to no avail. I simply don't understand how I'm supposed to configure relationships in EF Core, or how `modelBuilder` works. I would highly appreciate an explanation on how to avoid this error and what actually causes it. I thought that having a navigation property and a foreign key defined would be enough for EF Core to properly generate the relationships. I tried the online documentation for EF Core on relationships to no avail.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem here is that you're configuring Location to have ArtItems (which you commented out), and then in ArtItems say that they have a location. this is causing a circular reference, because they keep referencing each other. Just keep it simple : ArtItem has Location (referenced by foreign key). You should really keep the relations as simple as possible. Company should not have Country, Company should have Location, Location should have Country, etc...

Comment: I specifically commented that out because it's not a prop I am required to add in the API. It was me trying to fix the situation. The migration was created before that line of code was added.

Comment: ```public class ArtItem
    {
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }``` this is the fix you're suggesting, I assume. Even after removing the navigation prop, I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you using Ef or Ef Core? normally, you don't need to add the Id's, you can just say that for example it has a Location, and EF is smart enough to use it's Id as a foreign key. And be careful with composite keys, Ef cannot alter the Identity after the initial migration, so best to keep it simple.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ngHHgMf I have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer installed.

Comment: After removing the foreign key prop, and adding a navigation prop, I get this. `The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'ArtItem.Location' and 'Location.ArtItems'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse.`

Comment: Exactly how did you configure it? maybe look here: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/basics/entity-in-entityframework.aspx

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking me about my `DbContext` class?https://pastebin.com/84X77Er9 https://pastebin.com/xaqDvmG1 https://pastebin.com/34WgwVH9

Comment: I was asking about the modelbuilder configuration. but looking at your pastebins: Your location has a locationId, you should rename that to just Id. Ef doesn't know that locationId is the identity, unless you specify it in the location configuration

Comment: `Id` was the initial prop name, I forgot to edit it back after trying some stuff to fix this. Initial error is generated with prop named `Id` in the `Location` entity class.https://pastebin.com/ESV0c21Q here's the migration code for the `Locations` `CreateTable`.

Comment: When using Location as a child entity, you can just add location in the configuration, and Ef should automatically use it's Id, and map it to LocationId in the parent entity (even though that property doesn't exist)

Comment: Try to modify ReferentialAction.Cascade in FK_ArtItem_Locations_LocationId to ReferentialAction.NoAction. It will work, my friend :))

Comment: Yes, tomato, that did work, actually. But why? What causes this error? Also, doesn't this mean that if i delete the location, the ArtItem won't get deleted? Also, is there any way to implement this without screwing with the migration class?

Comment: New question: why is this the only relationship that generated this issue? It actually makes sense, if a location is deleted, I don't want the art item to also get deleted. But what caused this?